# teclado numérico o solo numeros React native

Tags: react-native

Buenos soy nuevo en react native y tengo la siguiente duda tengo un input y quiero que en el solo se ingresen numeros existe alguna forma para que solo se active el teclado numerico ?

Answer (score 2):

En React Native, para un `TextInput` puedes leer la guía completa de propiedades [aquí](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput).

Para resolver tu duda, nos podemos ayudar de una propiedad llamada `keyboardType` el cuál cambiará el tipo del teclado de acuerdo al uso que quieras ofrecer, de esta forma:

```
<TextInput keyboardType="numeric" />
```

[Más información](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#keyboardtype)

Cualquier duda, no olvides preguntar

Comment: si funciono muchas gracias, voy a leer la documentación muchas gracias